# Logging a list of programs during the day

Tags: windows, logging, administration

Just wondering if there is any way of logging a list of programs that have been run during the day (perhaps using WMI)? I'd like to write up a script that can do this.

E.g. I want to be able to see what programs users have been running each work day (for instance say a user never actually opened their work related programs, I want to be able to see this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to turn on *process auditing*, via MMC:

> *Local Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy*

then set *Audit process tracking*" to "*Success, Failure*", and apply.

This will fill your event log (Security) quite quickly, so make sure to [configure it as needed](https://superuser.com/questions/71776/windows-security-log-is-full/71791).
Process creation and exit are logged with event IDs 592 and 593 respectively. The PID, user, domain and full process name are logged too. It should be simple enough to access that data via WMI, or you can filter and export to text or XML with [`wevtutil`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848%28WS.10%29.aspx).

You may also be able to use MS Applocker to [audit application use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723693%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).